# Add typings to plain JS Module with export default-syntax

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

I would like to add typings to the "cipher-collection"-node-module but it doesn't work and I can't figure out how to do this. I had a look at the ressouces [1] [2] [3] and took a look at how it's done in RxJs but still I can't adapt it to this module.

*cipher-collection* has a src-folder where e.g. base64.js is located in:

`node_modules/cipher-collection/src/base64.js:`

```
import { isBrowser } from './helpers/index'

// Courtesy: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding#The_Unicode_Problem

const decode = input => isBrowser ? decodeURIComponent(atob(input).split('').map(c => '%' + ('00' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-2)).join('')) : atob(input)
const encode = input => isBrowser ? btoa(encodeURIComponent(input).replace(/%([0-9A-F]{2})/g, (match, p1) => String.fromCharCode(`0x${p1}`))) : btoa(input)

const btoa = isBrowser ? window.btoa : i => Buffer.from(i).toString('base64')
const atob = isBrowser ? window.atob : i => Buffer.from(i, 'base64').toString()

export default {
  decode,
  encode
}
```

I tried to add the file `node_modules/cipher-collection/index.d.ts` with the following content:

```
export namespace CipherCollection {
  export { base64 } from './src/base64';
}
```

src/**base64.d.ts**:

```
export namespace base64 {
  export function encode(obj: any): string;
  export function decode(obj: string): any;
}
```

I thought I can use base64 now for example like this:

```
import { base64 } from 'cipher-collection';
base64.encode("hello!");
```

or like this:

```
import { CipherCollection } from 'cipher-collection';
CipherCollection.base64.encode("hello!");
```

But typescript can't find base64. Any ideas how I can achieve this?

[1] https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/library-structures.html

[2] https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/module-d-ts.html

[3] https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/module-function-d-ts.html